# how to add datatype in sqllite connection

Tags: android

how do i add datatype in my sqllite create? i use this url  project http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-examplefor help
and modify my sql database with  more intries hwo do i add datatype of every field? is is my connection string below i want to add  datatype tell me correct method  code and cap field is  date time field  all other are text field i wanna dolike this 
 +"selectProperty varchar(50) ,  propertyValue  varchar(50) not null,

give me correct method how i add datatype in my connection than u

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key       
  autoincrement,name,cap,code,Location,Notes,Person);";                 
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **name text,cap text and for integer value use integer.**

**Like -**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key       
    autoincrement,name text,cap text,code text,Location double,Notes text,Person text);";                 
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}
```

Below datatypes available in Sqlite.

Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:

> ```
> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.
> ```

Comment: i do like this  tell me is correct format?
 String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement inreger,name varchar,cap varchar,code varchar,Location varchar,Notes varchar,Person varchar);";

Comment: String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement inreger,name varchar,cap varchar,code varchar,Location varchar,Notes varchar,Person varchar);";

Comment: @HayyaAnam only above datatypes available in android sqlite. No varchar data type is supported by android sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

Like the following:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer PRIMARY KEY, autoincrement 
inreger,name varchar,cap varchar,code varchar,Location varchar,Notes varchar,
Person varchar);";
db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}
```

Comment: i guess so, but i did not try it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key       
  autoincrement,name TEXT,cap TEXT,code integer,Location integer,Notes TEXT,Person TEXT);";                 
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}
```